# Separating a string?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

```
- (IBAction)doUpload:(id)sender {
    NSMutableString *str = [[NSMutableString alloc] initWithString:@"Selected: "];
    for(int i = 0; i < [appDelegate.notesArray count]; i++) {
        // UPLOAD STRINGS HERE
        if(selected[i]) {
            [str appendFormat:@"%@ ", [appDelegate.notesArray objectAtIndex:i]];
        }
    }

    UploadView *uploadview = (UploadView *)self.view;
    if(uploadview != nil) {
        [m_owner uploadString:str];
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Selected Values"     message:str delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alert show];
        [alert release];
        // [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
    }
}
```

In the above code, the `str` variable contains some values from the tableview cell. My tableview has multiple selection enabled, so `str` contains multiple values.

This code:

```
 [m_owner uploadString:str];
```

is used for uploading to gdoc, but when `str` contains multiple values, it uploads all the values at the same time. I want to separate the values, and then upload them one by one.

How can I do this?

Comment: What is gdoc? What is m_owner?  Why can't you just call uploadString on each string individually instead of appending them all into one string?

Comment: @Brian gdoc means google-document,m_orwner is the class go googledoc_loginpge,that mens m_orwner is the login user

Answer (score 1):

```
NSString *str = @"Hi ! I am iPhone Developer";

NSArray *myWords = [str componentsSeparatedByString:@"!"];

NSString *str1 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[myWords objectAtIndex:0]];

NSString *str2 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[myWords objectAtIndex:1]];

NSLog(@"%@",str1);

NSLog(@"%@",str2);
```

You will find in Log like this

Hi

I am iPhone Developer

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to separate the components you can try using the `componentsSeperatedByString:` method. As a result you will be getting an array of objects which you can use to iterate for uploading.

```
[yourString componentsSeparatedByString:separatorString];
```

hope this helps.

Comment: sir,what is separatorstring?and i have the values in str .

Comment: if (selected[i]) [str appendFormat:@"%@ ",[appDelegate.notesArray objectAtIndex:i]];
        [str componentsSeparatedByString:@","]; is this correct?

Comment: separatorString is the string which you can use to identify the components. It can be any string which you used to append the strings

Comment: if (selected[i]) [str appendFormat:@"%@ ,",[appDelegate.notesArray objectAtIndex:i]] i put this code and i get comma separated values,nd how to uplode these values one by one in g doc?thanks